# How can I get a sum of arrays of tuples in scala

Tags: scala

I have a simple array of tuples

```
val arr = Array((1,2), (3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10))
```

I wish to get `(1+3+5+7+9, 2+4+6+8+10)` tuple as the answer

What is the best way to get the sum as tuples, similar to regular arrays. I tried

```
val res = arr.foldLeft(0,0)(_ + _)
```

This does not work.

Sorry about not writing the context. I was using it in scalding with algebird. Algebird allows sums of tuples and I assumed this would work. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as `Tuple` addition, so that can't work. You would have to operate on each ordinate of the `Tuple`:

```
val res = arr.foldLeft(0,0){ case (sum, next) => (sum._1 + next._1, sum._2 + next._2) }

res: (Int, Int) = (25,30)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work nicely:

```
arr.foldLeft((0,0)){ case ((a0,b0),(a1,b1)) => (a0+a1,b0+b1) }
```

Addition isn't defined for tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Use scalaz, which defines a tuple as a semigroup, allowing you to use the append operator `|+|`

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

arr.fold((0,0))(_ |+| _)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative

```
val (a, b) =  arr.unzip
                       //> a  : Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
                       //| b  : Array[Int] = Array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
(a.sum, b.sum)        
                      //> res0: (Int, Int) = (25,30)
```

Comment: This one is not efficient, it will traverse the collection at three times (unzip, and two times sum).

Comment: Correct. It's also obvious, which I think is also important.